# Binding closure variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, bind

I'm wondering how I can bind variables to a closure function. Let me use this code:

Please see the code here:

```
function makeCall(callback) {
var fs = callback.toString();
var stored_callback = eval('(' + fs + ')').bind({ });
stored_callback();
}

function foo(id) {
makeCall(function() {
    console.log(id);
});
}
foo('bar');
```

After the call of eval, the called function cannot reach the id as it should as a closure.

My question is that before calling the toString, can I somehow retrieve the 'context' of a closure to be stored and retrieved and bind to the call?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand. `id` and `name` are accessible by the function you pass to `obj.do`, since it is a closure, no matter what `this` refers to. What is `callback` in `callback.bind( bobInstance );`? Maybe you have to provide a better example.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I hope it is more understandable now.

Comment: Ok, I might understand what you are trying to say now, but I cannot see the problem. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/xRLNM/. I bind the passed in callback, but it can still access `id`. Do you want to "change" the `id` and `name` values when you bind the callback to a different object? You might have have to provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo yourself to show the actual issue.

Comment: Thanks, let me share this to describe my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/3LfDK/1/

Comment: Ah. In that case the answer is no. It is not possible to do this. Whatever you are trying to achieve with this, there might be another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Felix King's answer, it cannot be done. :(
Too bad. I just wanted to store calls and executed later for some kind of persistence level. This way an interaction can be made even if the computer restarts or anything... It seems the only way is to not use the embedder parameters from the 'closure', huh? Thanks very much anyway!